# Reconstructing accumulator obj and reading its value in Spark Driver

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a problem in which i am counting number of errors occured in a spark streaming job and have to create metrics around it.

But i want to write metric creation logic in sparkdriver so that it create metric for entire spark job.

The approach i thought of is to create an accumlator and increment it as soon as i get the error by one.

Now i will write a sparkListener and use the accumlator value to generte metrics.

SO the issue is that i am not able to read value of accumlator from listener as it is a different class.

Can we reconstruct an accumlator in spark using sparkConstruct so that we can use the same accumlator across different componenets.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to find any proper way to reconstruct the accumulator from Spark Context but got a solution where i can read value of **named accumulators** on Spark Driver. For this we need to extend SparkListener and override **onStageCompleted** as shown below. Then we would be able to access all the accumulators in that particular driver program.

**Here is the sample code:**

**Main method**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final LongAccumulator acc;

    String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date());
    System.out.println(date);
    try {

        JavaSparkContext js = new JavaSparkContext("local[*]", "spark16");
        JavaStreamingContext jsc = new JavaStreamingContext(js, Durations.seconds(5));
        AccListener accList = new AccListener();
        acc = jsc.ssc().sc().longAccumulator("testStream");
        **jsc.sparkContext().sc().addSparkListener(accList);**
        JavaReceiverInputDStream<String> lines = jsc.socketTextStream("localhost", 12345);
        JavaDStream<String> ds = lines.map(new Function<String, String>() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            public String call(String arg0) throws Exception {
                System.out.println("Inside map: " + arg0);
                acc.add(1L);
                Thread.sleep(300);
                return arg0;
            }
        });
        ds.print();

        jsc.start();
        jsc.awaitTermination();
        jsc.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

    }
}
```

**AccListener.java**

```
class AccListener extends SparkListener {

@Override
public void onStageCompleted(SparkListenerStageCompleted stageCompleted) {
    super.onStageCompleted(stageCompleted);
    scala.collection.mutable.HashMap<Object, AccumulableInfo> map = stageCompleted.stageInfo().accumulables();
    Collection<Tuple2<Object, AccumulableInfo>> newMap = JavaConversions.asJavaCollection(map);
    System.out.println("onStageCompleted");
    for (Tuple2<Object, AccumulableInfo> t : newMap) {

        if (t._2.name().get().equalsIgnoreCase("testStream")) {
            System.out.println(t._1 + "    " + t._2.name().get() + "   " + t._2.value().get().toString());
        }
    }
   }
  }
```

**Reference**: https://gist.github.com/squito/2f7cc02c313e4c9e7df4